# Solving a PDE with a positively valued characteristic coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I want to confirm that I get the solution of the PDE with positive coefficient right.

I have the initial value problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t=\alpha u_xx  \ \ \ \ \ 0<x<L, t>0\\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0 \\
\end{cases}\\
u(x,0)=
\begin{cases}
0\ \ \ \  0<x<L/2\\
1\ \ \ \  L/2<x<L
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Set  $\alpha=1$, and using separation of variables, we get:

\begin{equation}
X_{xx}\pm k^2X=0\\
T_t=\pm k^2
\end{equation}

I would like to control the case of $k^2>0$, this gives with IC, that $k=\frac{1}{L}$

\begin{equation}
X(x)=A\cosh\frac{1}{L}x
\end{equation}

But when I use the second IC, in order to find A I get $A=0$ on $0<x<L$ and $\frac{1}{\cosh\frac{1}{L}x}$ on $L/2<x<L$. This gives

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
0, \ \ \ \ 0<x<L \\
e^{\frac{1}{L^2}t} , \ \ \ \ L/2<x<L
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

But this is not a complete function of two variables. What is wrong here?

Comment: From your equation for $X(x)$ you find the values of $k$ which satisfy the boundary conditions are $k=n\pi/L$, and that $X(x)=\cos(kx)$ You then have one value of $k$ for each integer $n$

Comment: @Sal Thanks, but the initial condition $u_x(0)=0$ is satisfied by  $\cosh kx$ ,which occurs for $k^2>0$ , because $u_x(x)=-k\sinh kx\rightarrow u_x(0)=\sinh0=0$. So this puzzles me, as it is not in disagreement with the I.C. So which part of the IC tells that we have to avoid $k^2>0$?